# Using `print()` to write to file opened in binary mode

Tags: python, byte

I often use `print()` instead of `file.write()` when writing to files in Python. Recently, I had to write out some binary data, and tried a similar pattern:

```py
f = open('test.txt', 'w')
f.write('abcd')
print('efgh', file=f)
f.close()

f = open('test.bin', 'wb')
f.write(b'abcd')  # works as expected
print(b'efgh', file=f)
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
f.close()
```

My first thought was the default newline-appending behaivor of `print()` might be at fault:

```py
print(b'efgh', file=f, end='')
# same error
print(b'efgh', file=f, end=None)
# same error
print(b'efgh', file=f, end=b'')
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
# TypeError: end must be None or a string, not bytes
print(b'efgh', file=f, end=b'\n')
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
# TypeError: end must be None or a string, not bytes
```

Unfortunately, none of the permutations of changing the end worked.

Why is this happening? I suspect that this use of `print()` might not be supported, but in that case the error message is quite confusing.

Comment: Try passing strings and use the encoding parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From python3 documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

> All non-keyword arguments are converted to strings like str() does and written to the stream, separated by sep and followed by end. Both sep and end must be strings; they can also be None, which means to use the default values. If no objects are given, print() will just write end.

As I understand, you can't write **bytes** with `print()` because the object you want to write is passed only as positional argument and positional arguments are converted to strings(hence the error).

Comment: I can't believe I didn't realize this and didn't try to check the docs. Of course it makes sense since you can `print()` basically anything and get reasonable output. Thanks!